# Equivalent infinitesimal for $\log(\cos(x))$

Tags: infinitesimals

I recently came across a limit problem which replaces $\log(\cos(x))$ with an equivalent infinitesimal $\cos(x) - 1$.

How do we prove that $\cos(x)-1$ is the equivalent infinitesimal for $\log(\cos(x))$?

Comment: It would be good if you would "accept" the given answer, so this question does no more appear as "open" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

$$ \ln(\cos(x))=\ln(1+\cos(x)-1)=\cos(x)-1 +o(\cos(x)-1)$$

Comment: Of course!. Thank you and silly of me.

Comment: You're welcome. Sillyness could appear in absent-mindedness of genius ;)